# @JsonClassDiscriminator doesn't change json class discriminator

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.serialization

**The Problem**

Due to project architecture, backward compatibility and so on, I need to change class discriminator on one abstract class and all classes that inherit from it. Ideally, I want it to be an enum.

I tried to use `@JsonClassDiscriminator` but Kotlinx still uses `type` member as discriminator which have name clash with member in class. I changed member name to test what will happen and Kotlinx just used `type` as discriminator.

Also, outside of annotations, I want to avoid changing these classes. It's shared code, so any non backward compatible changes will be problematic.

**Code**

I prepared some code, detached from project, that I use for testing behavior.

```
fun main() {
    val derived = Derived("type", "name") as Base
    val json = Json {
        prettyPrint = true
        encodeDefaults = true
        serializersModule = serializers
    }.encodeToString(derived)
    print(json)
}

@Serializable
@JsonClassDiscriminator("source")
data class Derived(
    val type: String?,
    val name: String?,
) : Base() {
    override val source = FooEnum.A
}

@Serializable
@JsonClassDiscriminator("source")
abstract class Base {
    abstract val source: FooEnum
}

enum class FooEnum { A, B }

internal val serializers = SerializersModule {
    polymorphic(Base::class) {
        subclass(Derived::class)
    }
}
```

If I don't change `type` member name, I got this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
> Polymorphic serializer for class my.pack.Derived has property 'type'
> that conflicts with JSON class discriminator. You can either change
> class discriminator in JsonConfiguration, rename property with
> @SerialName annotation or fall back to array polymorphism

If I do change the name, I got this JSON which clearly shows, that json type discriminator wasn't changed.

```
{
    "type": "my.pack.Derived",
    "typeChanged": "type",
    "name": "name",
    "source": "A"
}
```

Comment: I don't believe you're supposed to define `source` yourself as a property in the code. Kotlinx Serialization writes the value itself AFAIU

Comment: @Joffrey that's possible, but even with `@JsonClassDiscriminator("foo")` result is `"type": "my.pack.Derived"` which doesn't help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kotlinx Serialization doesn't allow for significant customisation of the default type discriminator - you can only change the name of the field.

##### Encoding default fields

Before I jump into the solutions, I want to point out that in these examples using `@EncodeDefault` or `Json { encodeDefaults = true }` is required, otherwise Kotlinx Serialization won't encode your `val source`.

```kotlin
@Serializable
data class Derived(
  val type: String?,
  val name: String?,
) : Base() {
  @EncodeDefault
  override val source = FooEnum.A
}
```

##### Changing the discriminator field

You can use [`@JsonClassDiscriminator`](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/json.md#class-discriminator-for-polymorphism) to define the name of the discriminator

(Note that you only need `@JsonClassDiscriminator` on the parent `Base` class, not both)

However, `@JsonClassDiscriminator` is more like an 'alternate name', not an override. To override it, you can set `classDiscriminator` in the `Json { }` builder

```kotlin
  val mapper = Json {
    prettyPrint = true
    encodeDefaults = true
    serializersModule = serializers
    classDiscriminator = "source"
  }
```

##### Discriminator value

[You can change the value of `type` for subclasses though](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/polymorphism.md#custom-subclass-serial-name) - use `@SerialName("...")` on your subclasses.

```kotlin
@Serializable
@SerialName("A")
data class Derived(
  val type: String?,
  val name: String?,
) : Base()
```

##### Including the discriminator in a class

You also can't include the discriminator in your class -  https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/issues/1664

So there are 3 options.

###### Closed polymorphism

Change your code to use [closed polymorphism](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/polymorphism.md#sealed-classes)

Since `Base` is a sealed class, instead of an enum, you can use type-checks on any `Base` instance

```kotlin
fun main() {
  val derived = Derived("type", "name")

  val mapper = Json {
    prettyPrint = true
    encodeDefaults = true
    classDiscriminator = "source"
  }

  val json = mapper.encodeToString(Base.serializer(), derived)
  println(json)

  val entity = mapper.decodeFromString(Base.serializer(), json)
  when (entity) {
    is Derived -> println(entity)
  }
}

@Serializable
@SerialName("A")
data class Derived(
  val type: String?,
  val name: String?,
) : Base()


@Serializable
sealed class Base
```

Since `Base` is now [sealed](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/sealed-classes.html), it's basically the same as an enum, so there's no need for your `FooEnum`.

```kotlin
  val entity = mapper.decodeFromString(Base.serializer(), json)
  when (entity) {
    is Derived -> println(entity)
    // no need for an 'else'
  }
```

However, you still need `Json { classDiscriminator= "source" }`...

##### Content-based deserializer

Use a [content-based deserializer](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/json.md#content-based-polymorphic-deserialization).

This would mean you wouldn't need to make `Base` a sealed class, and you could manually define a default if the discriminator is unknown.

```kotlin
object BaseSerializer : JsonContentPolymorphicSerializer<Base>(Base::class) {
  override fun selectDeserializer(element: JsonElement) = when {
    "source" in element.jsonObject -> {
      val sourceContent = element.jsonObject["source"]?.jsonPrimitive?.contentOrNull

      when (
        val sourceEnum = FooEnum.values().firstOrNull { it.name == sourceContent }
      ) {
        FooEnum.A -> Derived.serializer()
        FooEnum.B -> error("no serializer for $sourceEnum")
        else      -> error("'source' is null")
      }
    }
    else                           -> error("no 'source' in JSON")
  }
}
```

This is a good fit in some situations, especially when you don't have a lot of control over the source code. However, I think this is pretty hacky, and it would be easy to make a mistake in selecting the serializer.

##### Custom serializer

Alternatively you can write a custom serializer.

The end result isn't that different to the content-based deserializer. It's still complicated, and is still easy to make mistakes with. For these reasons, I won't give a complete example.

This is beneficial because it provides more flexibility if you need to encode/decode with non-JSON formats.

```kotlin
@Serializable(with = BaseSerializer::class)
@JsonClassDiscriminator("source")
sealed class Base {
  abstract val source: FooEnum
}

object BaseSerializer : KSerializer<Base> {

  override val descriptor: SerialDescriptor = buildClassSerialDescriptor("Base") {
    // We have to write our own custom descriptor, because setting a custom serializer
    // stops the plugin from generating one
  }

  override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): Base {
    require(decoder is JsonDecoder) {"Base can only be deserialized as JSON"}
    
    val sourceValue = decoder.decodeJsonElement().jsonObject["source"]?.jsonPrimitive?.contentOrNull

    // same logic as the JsonContentPolymorphicSerializer...
  }

  override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: Base) {
    require(encoder is JsonEncoder) {"Base can only be serialized into JSON"}

    when (value) {
      is Derived -> encoder.encodeSerializableValue(Derived.serializer(), value)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I know about classDiscriminator, but this would affect all serialization in project, which is a big no no, as it would cascade further and add a lot of work.
I'm looking into other solutions you provided :)